# libvirt-bin errors and cant install anything

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, virtualization

So I believe this started after I screwed up the upgrade from ubuntu 14 something to 16.04 and had to fix it.
I've tried many other searches about libvirt and no suggestions have yielded a fix.
including all of the suggestions in here:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2022671

Here is the error I get when I run:
`sudo apt-get install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 497 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libvirt-bin (1.3.1-1ubuntu10.2) ...
Job for libvirt-bin.service failed because the control process exited       
 with error code. See "systemctl status libvirt-bin.service" and   
 "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript libvirt-bin, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package libvirt-bin (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit   
 status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libvirt-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

And when I run:
    `systemctl status libvirt-bin.service`

```
● libvirt-bin.service - Virtualization daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirt-bin.service; enabled;     vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-23 02:28:34 EDT; 11min ago
     Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
           http://libvirt.org
  Process: 26720 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/libvirtd $libvirtd_opts (code=exited, status=6)
 Main PID: 26720 (code=exited, status=6)

Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 23 02:28:34 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
```

And when I run :`journalctl -xe`

```
-- 
-- Unit libvirt-bin.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 23 02:49:10 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 23 02:49:10 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 23 02:49:11 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Sep 23 02:49:11 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
-- Subject: Unit libvirt-bin.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirt-bin.service has finished shutting down.
Sep 23 02:49:11 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: libvirt-bin.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 23 02:49:11 alex-S400CA systemd[1]: Failed to start Virtualization daemon.
-- Subject: Unit libvirt-bin.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit libvirt-bin.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Sep 23 02:49:13 alex-S400CA sudo[27045]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```